# Updating from such a repository can't be done securely and repository is not signed errors

Tags: linux, ubuntu-20.04

I run `sudo apt-get update` then I get this error

```
Hit:1 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease
Hit:2 https://deb.nodesource.com/node_16.x focal InRelease                 
Err:3 http://ph.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease                             
  403  Forbidden [IP: 202.79.184.254 80]
Err:4 http://ph.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease                     
  403  Forbidden [IP: 202.79.184.254 80]
Hit:5 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease         
Err:6 http://ph.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease      
  403  Forbidden [IP: 202.79.184.254 80]
Hit:7 http://ppa.launchpad.net/openjdk-r/ppa/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:8 http://ppa.launchpad.net/otto-kesselgulasch/gimp/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:9 http://ppa.launchpad.net/sylvain-pineau/kazam/ubuntu focal InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
E: The repository 'http://ph.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease' is not signed.
E: Failed to fetch http://ph.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal/InRelease  403  Forbidden [IP: 202.79.184.254 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://ph.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-updates/InRelease  403  Forbidden [IP: 202.79.184.254 80]
E: The repository 'http://ph.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: Failed to fetch http://ph.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-backports/InRelease  403  Forbidden [IP: 202.79.184.254 80]
E: The repository 'http://ph.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

I tried searching everywhere and checked related topics but none seems working.
How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

I have passed through the same problem. The solution was to change my internet connection. The problem seem to have been the firewalls in my corporation network that gave me the same exact messages, including the IP address that you've pasted.

Answer (score 0):

I changed my network connection to a different one and that worked for me. I think firewall of the first network disabled updates to save bandwidths or something like that.

Answer (score -1):

Had the same error but with a different repository.
Try this out if it works for you.

```
ls /etc/apt/sources.list.d
```

listing the repositories.

```
rm -i /etc/apt/sources.list.d/output of 1
```

Then of course run.

```
apt upgrade
```

More details in the screenshots in these links.

Comment: Deleting the repositories from your apt config is hardly a "fix".

Comment: But it solves the problem